# What is the purpose of the Vref in this opamp comparator circuit?

Tags: operational-amplifier, sensor, comparator, wheatstone-bridge

I am designing a simple circuit for a sensork, and this was an example circuit given by the manufacturer. The sensor is a magnetic sensor in a standard wheatstone bridge arrangement. I was wondering what the purpose of the Vref is. Why not just input the Vout+ directly to the opamp?

[image: Voltage Comparator circuit]

Comment: this is not a comparator circuit

Answer (score 4):

> I was wondering what the purpose of the Vref is

What you have is called a differential amplifier and, the ratio of R3 and R4 should be the same as the ratio of R1 and R2: -

[image]

When you use a "ref" voltage instead of 0V the output from the differential amplifier is "referenced" to the ref voltage. A typical example might be to make ref = 2.5 volts and, when the sensor output is "neutral" or balanced, the output from the op-amp is 2.5 volts. This makes it suitable for connecting to an ADC that has a 5V input span range.

As you can see in the example circuit in the question, the op-amp is powered from 5 V and 0 V (earth) and so a ref voltage of 2.5 volts seems appropriate.

> Why not just input the Vout+ directly to the opamp?

If you did that you would lose your stable point of reference. I assume that the sensor is a 4 element bridge and that all four elements can vary depending on what is being sensed. If only two elements were active then you could use the junction of the static elements but you would also need to rely on your 5 volt supply being stable.

Answer (score 1):

The op-amp operates from 5V/0V so the output for a balanced bridge would be 0V, and it would not be able to go quite to 0V. Also, for a differential amplifier you'd normally want to connect the Vout+ to two resistors with ratio R2/R1 to keep the gain the same from each input. For a differential amplifier with a bipolar supply (+5/-5V, for example) you would ground the divider.

In this case, you probably want that same resistor ratio (R3/R4 = R2/R1) but you would like the output voltage to be 2.5V with the bridge balanced. So you apply a reference voltage to bias the output.

If the bridge has a 2.5V output at balance on each output the reference voltage would be 2.5V, but if it is different then things get a lot more complicated and the reference depends on the gain of the amplifier.

It should be noted that the bridge is ratiometric but the reference (unless derived from a voltage divider itself, perhaps buffered) is not so the output span will shift with the supply voltage but the zero will not. If the output goes to a ratiometric ADC (reference is the supply) then the zero will vary greatly with the supply voltage.

Comment: If the OP wants a ratiometric reference -- the [TLE2426 "rail splitter" chip](http://www.ti.com/product/TLE2426/description) provides that in a single package, btw :)